# Android: DialogFragment wrap content width when hiding default border

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

I have a custom dialog view I am displaying with rounded corners.  Because of this I need to hide default Dialog border frame which I am successfully doing with, getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));.

My problem is the dialog now extends the whole parent width where I only want it to display roughly 90% of the width like a normal dialog window.  I've tried setting getWindow().setLayout(...) and also setting layout param attributes but no avail.  Any help is much appreciated.

*UPDATE. removing getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0)); from my code fixes the width issue but brings me back to the problem of that default dialog border showing. Though because my custom dialog has no borders and rounded corners I need that border gone without losing that 90% or whatever dialog width like most dialogs.

```
public final class ResetPasswordDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

  public static ResetPasswordDialogFragment newInstance() {
    ResetPasswordDialogFragment f = new ResetPasswordDialogFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
   }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_password_reminder, container, false);

    //Removes the default dialog background border
    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));

    Button resetBtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.resetPasswordBtn);
    Button closeBtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.closeBtn);

    //Click Listeners
    resetBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO web call here
        }
    });
    closeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           dismiss();
        }
    });

    return v;
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to set width and height dynamically ?
If not then you can give the layout_width and layout_height parameters to your dialog_fragment_reminder xml file

Comment: i have both of those set to wrap_content in my layout though i also tried setting a fixed width like 100dp to test and the dialog window still fills the whole screen. BUT ONLY when I am hiding the default dialog border.

Comment: I think you need to create a custom dialog and give it specific parameters : try looking here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: Though I am creating one. The onCreateView in my sample code is inside of my ResetPasswordDialogFragment which extends DialogFragment.

Comment: I updated my code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution for you or help you in your sample code but what i would do is create a custom dialog in your activity or any event which triggers a dialog like this :

```
          dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),R.style.Theme_CustomDialog);
          dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
          dialog.show();
```

and in your Theme_Custom dialog if you want to remove the borders just  give

```
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

and then in your custom_dialog xml file give a linear/relative layout with parameters you want to pass and views you want your custom dialog box to have

Alternatively you can have a look here : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html and also http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/01/dialogfragment.html

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't solve my problem. I'm curious if the use of DialogFragment is posing some sort of trickier.  My problem is simple...I don't want the width to fill the parent. Though the common-sense approach of setting wrapped_content or event a fixed width is not solving it.